# Protect Url access from vendor user in magento

Tags: magento

I am new to magento. I have logged in as a vendor user and accesses all vendor pages. But I am able to access customer's dashboard also. I just want to redirect to vendor dashboard when vendor enter customer dashboard url.

How can i do this in magento?
Can anyone help me???

Thanks on advance.

Comment: which extension you are using for vendor functionality ?

Comment: I am using customer functionality for both vendor and customer, the only difference in group id that i have stored in session. if group id is 4 then it is vendor else customer.

Comment: so have you developed any vendor dashboard ?

Comment: yes, i have developed it.

Comment: you must provide full details for the solutions. You can check condition if logged in user have vendor group then redirect on vendor dashboard. instead of customer dashboard

Comment: I got the solution. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In customer controller inside dashboard functionality, I have used the following code to protect the url of customers:

Code:

```
if(Mage::getSingleton("customer/session")->getCustomer()->getGroupid()==4){
        $this->_redirect('marketplace/vendor/dashboard/');
    }
```